# Passing Data Between RecyclerView inside Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a ViewPager with 2 Fragments, FragA and FragB. Inside each Fragment I have a RecyclerView. When a user presses a button inside the RecyclerView in FragB I would like to remove the respective Object from that RecyclerView's ArrayList and add it to the RecyclerView contained in FragA.

Can I directly pass the Object from one RecyclerView's Adapter to the other? Or do I need to pass the Object from the RecyclerView Adapter to FragB then to the Activity containing the ViewPager then to FragA before finally passing to the RecyclerView inside FragA?

Comment: The default Android way would be to communicate from a fragment to the activity (interface) and then back to the fragment (arguments or setter). But a Bus solution would be much simpler ;) have a look at tinybus, otto or eventbus

Answer (score 0):

Your fragments and activity is just to present data.
I think the best solution is to use good design, like MVC pattern, or at least some model class (model-view kind of pattern), wich will have referens to both lists and can have public method for moving object between lists.

Giving both lists to both fragments so they can move objects is bad design choise IMHO.
This question is not for adapter solution at all.